# What does 否定を上回る mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 否定イコールダメではないのでは。**否定を、上回る**、意志や考えを、持たない限り、他人に振り回されるだけ。夢は、かなわないのではなく、それに向かって努力し、行動しない限り、現実にならないだけ。否定を、どう生かすかです♪

I can't understand it, can someone help me? I don't think it's "surpass a denial"... I just want to know what 否定を上回る means, I think it will help me understand this sentence

I found it here http://tell-me.jp/q/2373128

Comment: The question title should summarize your question.  Your *actual* question should be in the question body, with enough detail to let people write specific and helpful answers.  Your question should not consist entirely of a quote.

Comment: Could you also explain what part of the sentence you do understand (and also give the source of the sentence)? This would help answerers tremendously.

Comment: I just want to know what 否定を上回る means, sorry, I made this too confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Surpass a denial" makes sense here I think. OK, it probably can be reworded in a way that sounds much better in English, but the basic idea is here. As we can see from the original question you linked to, that woman's dream is being "denied" (否定されたら) by someone. As in, someone is trying to make it impossible I guess (maybe like a parent saying "you shouldn't become a teacher" or something?). But it's all in her hands and she can overcome (surpass) this obstacle if she tries hard enough. So I believe your interpretation is more or less correct. I wonder what other people will say...

Comment: I second with you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure so much if this could be a big deal regarding **the original text**. Japanese is SOV, so here the original text is saying.......

> 否定を、上回る、意志や考えを、持たない限り、他人に振り回されるだけ。
>
> here, O-V-O-V-「V-conditional」-「passive-clause.」
>
> The first O is 否定、the denial.
>
> The second V is 上回る、surpass or excel,
>
> The third O is ( are ) ( your ) will or thought,
>
> The fourth "V-conditional" is, "unless you have ( the prior O, so, your will, thought. )
>
> The last "passive clause" is, "you would then get pushed around by others.

So if I translate the previous O-V-O-V-「V-conditional」-「passive-clause.」.

That would be

> "Unless you do not have a stronger, better will or thought that excels the denial, you would get pushed around by others and you would not be ( or have ) yourself".